# The conditions for an independent but not IID exponential random variable to converge in distribution to 0

Tags: measure-theory, martingales

Would anyone be able to check if I've missed anything for my answer to the following question. The requirements I've noted so far is that:

For every bounded and continuous $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ , $F_{X_n}(x) \rightarrow F_X(x)$ at every $x$ where the limit distribution function $F_X$ is continuous. As a consequence of it converging in $L^1$ , it must also converge in measure by the following inequality

$\mu\left(\left\{x \in X:\left|f_n(x)-f(x)\right|>\varepsilon\right\}\right) \leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int\left|f_n-f\right| d \mu$.

Comment: Very vaguely worded. What sequence is convergent in $L^{1}$ and what sequence should converge in measure?

Comment: ah, I should've put the sequence of random variables where f is the identity function for the last inequality.